# Choosing an object from a form in php

Tags: php, forms, class, object

Okay, so I have a drop-down menu where the user is supposed to select an object which is defined elsewhere in the php project. I have tried the following:

```
<form method="post">
    <select name="ball">
        <option name="red" value=?>Red Ball</option>
        <option name="blue" value=?>Blue Ball</option>
    </select>
    <input type="submit">
</form>
```

Where Ball is defined in another file by:

```
class Ball {
     public function __construct($color) {
           $this->color=$color;
      }

     public function getColor() {
           return $this->color;
     }
}
$redBall = new Ball("red");
$blueBall = new Ball("blue");
```

I want the user to be able to select either $redBall or $blueBall from the drop down menu, but I don't know what to put for the "value" in the option part. I tried

```
value=$redBall
```

But that didn't work, any ideas?

**EDIT**
I think there is some confusion about what I am asking from some of the answers so far.

I am looking for a way to have the value BE the object $redBall, for example later on in the code I would like to take their selection and write $_POST['ball']->color. I don't know if there is a better way to do this, but the actual class I am working with has multiple attributes, and I want the user selection to allow me to access all of them like it were an object

Comment: Do you really need a `name` attribute for an `option` element? Just change `name` to `value`.

Comment: Are you ever gonna use the other ball? If not, why create two of them in the first place? `$value = new Ball( $_POST['ball'] );` (If you want to limit the colors that can be used to a given set, then use an array of those to check against first.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on your comment from another answer try doing something like:

```
class Ball {
    var $color;

    public function __construct($color) {
        $this->color=$color;
    }

    public function getColor() {
        return $this->color;
    }
}

$balls = array(
    "red" => new Ball("red"),
    "blue" => new Ball("blue")
);
```

Your form should then look like

```
<form method="post">
    <select name="ball">
        <option value="red">Red Ball</option>
        <option value="blue">Blue Ball</option>
    </select>
    <input type="submit">
</form>
```

Then when you process the form that was submitted just do

```
$selectedBall = $balls[$_POST["ball"]];
echo $selectedBall->getColor();
```

Answer (score 2):

If you need precisely the value to be edited, do this:

```
<form method="post">
    <select name="ball">
        <option name="red" value = '<?php echo $redball->color;  ?>' > Red ball</option>
        <option name="blue" value = '<?php echo $blueball->color;  ?>' >Blue ball</option>
    </select>
    <input type="submit">
</form>
```

I think you need to fix your ball class as well though, you may need to add:

```
public $color;
```

in the class.

**EDIT:** -- The question requires the **full object** be sent via the select control. --

Select elements can only send text, and objects can't quite be described by text normally. Thankfully, we have [JSON](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_json_intro.asp). JSON allows us to take a PHP object and convert it and its values to text.

we have to turn the objects into JSON strings, like this:

```
$blueJSON = json_encode($blueball);
$redJSON = json_encode($redball);
```

Then make the value portion of the selects be equal to these new variables.

```
<option name="red" value = '<?php echo $redJSON;  ?>' > Red ball</option>
<option name="blue" value = '<?php echo $blueJSON;  ?>' >Blue ball</option>
```

When you receive these objects wherever you use your form submission, decode them using json_decode();

```
$newRedBall = json_decode($_POST['red']);
$newBlueBall = json_decode($_POST['blue']);
```

Using this method you can send any object, without having to predefine your object at the start of a function. Helpful when you're dealing with user input.

**Warning:**

I usually pass JSON values to javascript, as sending an object like this isn't very common. I'm not entirely sure what your results will be, but hopefully this works for you.

Comment: Thank you, but I think you misunderstood the question. I am looking for a way to have the value BE the object $redBall, for example later on in the code I would like to take their selection and write $_POST['ball']->color. I don't know if there is a better way to do this, but the actual class I am working with has multiple attributes, and I want the user selection to allow me to access all of them like it were an object.

Comment: I see what you mean now. My apologies. I will update my answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can write it down like below :-

```
<form method="post">
    <select name="ball">
        <option name="red" value="<?=$redBall->getColor();?>">Red Ball</option>
        <option name="blue" value="<?=$blueBall->getColor();?>">Blue Ball</option>
    </select>
    <input type="submit">
</form>
```